# Create a rolling custom EWMA on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a rolling EWMA with the following decay= 1-ln(2)/3 on the last 13 values of a df such has :

```
factor
Out[36]: 
    EWMA
0  0.043
1  0.056
2  0.072
3  0.094
4  0.122
5  0.159
6  0.207
7  0.269
8  0.350
9  0.455
10 0.591
11 0.769
12 1.000
```

I have a df of monthly returns like this :

```
change.tail(5)
Out[41]: 

date                                                                                                                                    
2016-04-30      0.033         0.031     0.010     0.007     0.014    -0.006    -0.001      0.035    -0.004     0.020     0.011     0.003
2016-05-31      0.024         0.007     0.017     0.022    -0.012     0.034     0.019      0.001     0.006     0.032    -0.002     0.015
2016-06-30     -0.027        -0.004    -0.060    -0.057    -0.001    -0.096    -0.027     -0.096    -0.034    -0.024     0.044     0.001
2016-07-31      0.063         0.036     0.048     0.068     0.053     0.064     0.032      0.052     0.048     0.013     0.034     0.036
2016-08-31     -0.004         0.012    -0.005     0.009     0.028     0.005    -0.002     -0.003    -0.001     0.005     0.013     0.003
```

I am just trying to apply this rolling EWMA to each columns. I know that pandas has a EWMA method but I can't figure out how to pass the right 1-ln(2)/3 factor.

help would be appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `ewm` with `mean()`

```
df.ewm(halflife=1 - np.log(2) / 3).mean()
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do this with numpy?

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared do you know if it's possible to only use the last 13 values?

Answer (score 6):

@piRSquared 's answer is a good approximation, but values outside the last 13 also have weightings (albeit tiny), so it's not totally correct.

`pandas` could do rolling window calculations. However, amongst all the rolling function it supports, `ewm` is not one of them, which means we have to implement our own.

Assuming `series` is our time series to average:

```
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

window = 13
alpha = 1-np.log(2)/3    # This is ewma's decay factor.
weights = list(reversed([(1-alpha)**n for n in range(window)]))
ewma = partial(np.average, weights=weights)
rolling_average = series.rolling(window).apply(ewma)
```

Comment: it looks like ln and weight are not defined here, just fyi. I think it should be np.log and weights respectively